# Make div appear and change the whole html to be darker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div and after I click a button, I would like the div to appear (which I can do), but I would like the whole background to become darker too (this is inline with overlays).

I've tried using opacity - I change the opacity of the whole html with jQuery, i.e. `$('html').css('opacity','-0.5');` and change back the opacity of the div to normal, but for some reason, the opacity of the div stays the same (0.5). 
I don't quite like the opacity since actually it doesn't make the background darker (rather lighter).

Comment: If the div has a black background then higher opacity values will make the background darker, and lower ones will make it lighter.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

HTML--

```
<a id="some-button" href="#">click me</a>
<div id="overlay-back"></div>
<div id="overlay"><span>YOUR HTML GOES HERE</span></div>
```

CSS--

```
html, body {
    width  : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}
#overlay-back {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    background : #000;
    opacity    : 0.6;
    filter     : alpha(opacity=60);
    z-index    : 5;
    display    : none;
}

#overlay {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 100%;
    z-index  : 10;
    display  : none;
}
```

JS--

```
$('#some-button').on('click', function () {
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeIn(500);
});
```

Then just add your youtube video embed code to the `overlay` div and style it appropriately to put it where you want on the page.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EtHbf/1/

Comment: This covers only viewable part of the window, not entire page, if you scroll down

Comment: @jvk If you want the overlay to cover the viewport even when you scroll then you can use `position : fixed`. If you want to make it so users can't scroll (the page can scroll behind a `position : fixed` element) then when you show the overlay you can make the overflow of the `html` and `body` elements `hidden`: `html, body { overflow : hidden }`. If you do this you will likely need to save the scroll position which you can do by setting the height of the `body` element before setting it's `overflow` property to `hidden`. E.g `$('body').css({ height : $('body').height(), overflow : 'hidden' })`

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eys3d/741/) and [here](http://gasparesganga.com/labs/jquery-loading-overlay/)  with **more overlay effects**. Hope helps.

Answer (score 14):

This can be now done even easier than before. Just use absoluted box-shadow.

```css
 #yourDIV {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 5000px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 }
```

Comment: Instead of the 5000px value you could use 100vmax which is more adaptable.

Answer (score 4):

First, for opacity, you don't set a negative number.  `$('html').css('opacity','1');` is solid and completely visible, and `$('html').css('opacity','0');` is completely invisible.  Anything in between (0.2, 0.5, 0.7) gets more visible the close it is to 1.

Second, to make the background darker you can do this:

1. Create a div that fills the screen
2. Set z-index on that div higher than all content
3. Set background to black and opacity to 0.5
4. Put youtube video in another div with a higher z-index than the div you just made with the black background

Comment: 1. I would like the content of the html still to be visible, but only darker. 2-4 I've already done this.

Comment: Indeed I use 0.5 (instead of -0.5). Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want a 'modal' dialog.  It's basically accomplished by using an underlying div and a background set.

jQuery UI supports it here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal , but you can see how they do it by inspecting.

Comment: Are you saying there is no simple shortcut to do this? I thought it is couple of lines of jquery/html code

Comment: $('#modal').dialog({modal:true});  is pretty simple, when using that library.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// video lightbox
$('.video_popup').height($(document).height());
// GET WINDOW SCROLLtop OFFSET
var winScrT;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  winScrT = $(window).scrollTop();
});
$.getDocHeight = function() {
  var D = document;
  return Math.max(Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight), Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight), Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight));
};


$('.play').click(function() {

  $('.video_popup').height($.getDocHeight);

  $('#popup').css({
    top: (winScrT + 15) + 'px'
  });

  $('.video_popup').fadeTo(0, 0).css({
    marginLeft: '0px'
  }).fadeTo(600, 0.6);
});

$('.popup_close, .video_popup').click(function() {
  $('.video_popup').fadeTo(600, 0, function() {
    $('.video_popup').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.video_popup {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9000px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 300;
}

.popup_content {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 560px;
  color: #fff;
}

.popup_close {
  position: absolute;
  right: -55px;
  top: -25px;
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a class="play" href="javascript:void(0);">PLAY</a></p>

<div class="video_popup">
  <div class="popup_content">
    <a class="popup_close" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="_/images/close.png"></a>
    <object width="560" height="315">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/-pJcKCqxtAM?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&atuoplay=1">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/-pJcKCqxtAM?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&atuoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"/>
    </object>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The demo doesn't seem to do anything in IE9.

Comment: Very important line $('.video_popup').height( $(document).height() ) for longer pages. Thanks again

Comment: @Jasper THANKS! (P.S. I don't have IE9 to test but thanks a LOT for the TIP, appreciate it)

Comment: @user1073201 the `$.getDocHeight` is actually a GREAT function, it will calculate CROSS-BROWSER the document height!

Comment: @Jasper hm, the demo stalls in IE8 too. I'll fix it tomorrow properly (this was a hardcore copy-paste from an earlier project of mine (That btw works in all browsers.) )

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example of this behavior, in the demo: click the "watch video" link to fade in the video and screen dimmer divs (escape to fade out)

**[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/fBrUS/)**

CSS:

```
#screenDimmer,#video {display:none;position:absolute;}
#screenDimmer {top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:#000;opacity:.5;
    /* ie opacity */ -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";filter:alpha(opacity=50);}
#video {top:50%;left:50%;margin-left:-240px;margin-top:-193px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="screenDimmer"></div>
<div id="video"><!-- embedded video here --></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

hi i changed the code of someone who posted here, even though this may be solved already here is the updated code of jasper

html:

```
<a id="some-button" href="#">click me</a> 
<div id="overlay-back"></div> 
<div id="overlay"><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/08DjMT-qR9g" width="340" 
height="250"></iframe><br><br><button id="close"><img    
src="http://icongal.com/gallery/image/89825/remove_close_button_x_delete.png" 
height="50"
width="50"></button></div>
```

css:

```
html, body {
width  : 100%;
height : 100%;
}
#overlay button{
opacity:0.5;
}
#overlay button:hover{
opacity:1;   
}
#overlay-back { 
position   : absolute; 
text-align :center; 
width      : 100%; 
height     : 100%; 
background : #000; 
opacity    : 0.75; 
filter     : alpha(opacity=60); 
z-index    : 5;
display    : none;
}  
#overlay { 
position : absolute; 
text-align :center;
width    : 100%; 
height   : 100%; 
z-index  : 10;
display  : none;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('#some-button').on('click', function () { 
$('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeIn(1000); 
});
$('#close').on('click',function(){
$('#overlay,#overlay-back').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

i hope this might still help you and that this edit may be usefull to some people

added by me (close button,changed very little part of the css and used a youtube vid instead of nothing)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I have seen to achieve it is this:

```
$("#overlay").css("-webkit-filter","blur(5px)");
$("#overlay").css("-moz-filter","blur(5px)");
$("#overlay").css("-o-filter","blur(5px)");
$("#overlay").css("-ms-filter","blur(5px)");
$("#overlay").css("filter","blur(5px)");
$("#overlay").css("pointer-events", "none");
```

On clicking a button we have to run above steps. "overlay" is the ID of div which we want to be blur. After successful execution of script, at the end we can do this to re-enable the div:

```
$("#overlay").removeAttr("style");
```