# Name of Effect and How to Use

Tags: jquery

What's the name of effect when we click at a video and it appear bigger at the screen and the background of the page turns dark?

It's the samething when we use galleries like fancybox gallery,

but what about videos?

How to use?
And what's the correct name of this effect?

Thanks

Comment: The effect is called 'modal'. Ie. a modal window, where the background becomes inaccessible (greyed out normally) until the window which has focus has it's primary action completed or cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking this out: [jQuery Modal](http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/)

Also, check this question: [Make div appear larger and change the whole html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460420/make-div-appear-and-change-the-whole-html-to-be-darker)