# let fading background and dialog pop out

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make the background fade to black and let a div dialog pop out at the center. e.g

```
<div id=dialog style='position:fixed'>hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460531/3291093

As posted:

HTML:

```
<a id="some-button" href="#">click me</a>
<div id="overlay-back"></div>
<div id="overlay"><span>YOUR HTML GOES HERE</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width  : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}
#overlay-back {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    background : #000;
    opacity    : 0.6;
    filter     : alpha(opacity=60);
    z-index    : 5;
    display    : none;
}

#overlay {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 0;
    left     : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 100%;
    z-index  : 10;
    display  : none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#some-button').on('click', function () {
    $('#overlay, #overlay-back').fadeIn(500);
});
```